# Error : When i try to install php 7 version on centos 7 but Package comes Php 5 version

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, centos

When I try to install the PHP 7 version on my centos 7 but the Package comes from  Php 5 version so I decided to change the repo rebel to Remi and disable the rebel after I got the below error
[image]

Comment: Exactly how are you trying to install PHP 7? All that log shows is that you're trying to install some extensions that requires PHP 7.4 while having PHP 5.4 installed. You should post the initial commands as well, and you should post all that as _text_, not as images.

Comment: Perhaps a yum plugin.. such a priority... as explained by the wizard
https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/  (If the priorities plugin is enabled, ensure remi-php74 have higher priority (a lower value) than base and updates)

Answer (score 0):

I started a Docker container using `centos:7` and I ran the following commands:

```
yum -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
yum -y install https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
yum -y install yum-utils
yum-config-manager --disable 'remi-php*'
yum-config-manager --enable   remi-php74
yum -y update
yum -y install php
yum -y install php-fpm php-gd php-json php-mbstring php-mysqlnd php-xml php-xmlrpc php-opcache
```

Now let's see the `php`version.

```
sh-4.2# php -v
PHP 7.4.27 (cli) (built: Dec 14 2021 17:17:06) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.4.27, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

sh-4.2# php-fpm -v
PHP 7.4.27 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Dec 14 2021 17:17:06)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.4.27, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Again... see the wizard instructions... https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/
(you install php72-php packages, designed for multiple versions, see "single version", and drop the php72 prefixe)

Comment: Hi @RemiCollet! Thanks for the feedback, I've edited my answer. :) - It is working, I tested these commands in a new `centos:7` container.

Comment: now, got following error

Comment: Error: Package: php-opcache-7.4.27-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php74)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 7.4.27-1.el7.remi
           Installing: php-common-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-48.el7
Error: Package: php-json-7.4.27-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php74)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 7.4.27-1.el7.remi
           Installing: php-common-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-48.el7

Comment: [root@R2 ~]# php -v
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Apr  1 2020 04:07:17)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
[root@R2 ~]#

Comment: @GOWTHAMGUNASEELAN I updated the commands, try again please.

Comment: as I already said, may be related to priority plugin (full yum output may help), try with --noplugins  option (or --disableplugin=prority)